# How to turn back to old gnome panel style in GNOME 3?

Tags: gnome, arch-linux

Yesterday my gnome panel looked like [image: this one].

I restart the computer and (apparently this enabled some update) and now it looks like [image: this].

Which (in my opinion) is terrible because is missing a lot a features present in the old one, like Ethernet/3G network connection configuration/status, bluetooth configuration/status, etc.

How can I change back to the old one?

PS:I'm using Arch Linux.

**PS2:** I'm hopping I can do this without rolling back gnome (some sort configuration file or something like that)

Answer (score 0):

The look and feel of your desktop is controlled by which Window Manager you are using.  [Arch Linux supports a wide variety of Window Managers.](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Window_Manager).  I'd recommend trying to use MetaCity because it is likely similar to whatever you were using before.

I've never used arch linux specifically, but in most linux distributions you can install a new window manager and then log in screen will give you an option of choosing that window manager when you log in.

Comment: This isn't a answer to question.

Comment: I'm suggesting that you switch to a different window manager that looks more like what you are used to.

Answer (score 0):

When a feature is present differently than in the previous version, it doesn't mean it's missing. You should check all the active elements in the top right corner for the supposedly missing functionality and see whether it's actually missing. Notably the user menu in the very corner may have taken over some of the elements.

You'd better get used to Gnome folks changing stuff all the time for better or worse, or move away to some other option. I don't think they will change themselves ;).

NetworkManager (feel free to add back the tag if you were indeed interested in that) is a system daemon. How it is presented in Gnome 3 is another thing. You should also distinguish Gnome Shell's NetworkManager applet (called *network-indicator* and Gnome Control Center networking module that is usually launched from the applet.

You can always run `gnome-control-center` separately or you can run the original `nm-connection-editor` tool if in doubt. When some option disappeared for you, it may have various reasons, for example Bluez 5 integration in NetworkManager is far from finished but AFAIK Blues 5 is actively promoted by Gnome 3.8 developers.

Comment: the screenshots are not from my computer, I'm comparing only the upper right panel, which does miss a lot a features compared to the old one

Comment: @RSFalcon7 As I said, it most probably doesn't miss *any* features, as the Gnome folks moved a couple of things under the user menu. You should verify carefully whether you miss *features* or *icons*.

Comment: from my perspective, if I can't find a feature it means it is missing. Even tough it can be available in the menu (I couldn't find the 3G modem configurator, despite the documentation of the NetworkManager claims to configure it)

Comment: @RSFalcon7 If it's available in the menu, it's not missing. NetworkManager is a system daemon and its documentation doesn't (and cannot!) cover Gnome at all.

Comment: I only mean that the package is still installed, and therefore it is probably still available through some CLI

Comment: @RSFalcon7: It's available through various CLI and GUI tools and unless you carefully checked otherwise, most probably also through Gnome Shell.